# Quick edit will not appear in some views but will inside others

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, list-view, web-part-property, quick-edit

I have created a list with different views and each view is a standard view style. I set up a link to the view and edit the web part properties to show the tool bar. Now before I selected show tool bar the page was able to be quick edited but after I made the change it will no longer allow me to quick edit it.

I wanted to make note that the list is not grouped, style is set to default, tubular > allow individual item checkboxes has been checked off, there are no rich text fields.

Why can I see a list view under the toolbars New, Action and Settings but not in the other image.
[image: Quick edit not working and not view options below toolbar]

I also see there are page view options on some views but not others and some of the options in the web part properties disappear! I do not know how to fix this issue. you can see the difference in views via the images attached.

[image: Quick edit now works with view options below]

No one view which has quick edit enabled was set up with a tool bar with out my intervention.

the second view with quick edit disabled had a different format and I only added the show tool bar there.

Once I did this the quick edit option is not enabled anymore.

Why is are the view options available here on the one above but not in the one below and why are there items to be selected in the image above.

[image: Quick launch edit link]

I also set up my quick launch links to point to the view as seen above.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You apparently have to have Tablular View turned on for a view in order for Quick Edit to work.

[image: tabular view]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with Webpart rather this is the problem with the View.

Change the view settings -> Style -> Default

Comment: The view style is Default and still Quick Edit will not become available